# scrollbar visible on fullscreen mode

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome

I made an image viewer app, that just sends an image to a TV using a raspberry, displaying it on the connected screen via HDMI. The displaying software is Chrome, but I have a tiny problem:

There is a very small area of 4px I have to crop the bottom of the image in order to not see a scroll bar.

Example: Screen Res is 1024 x 768

- using a 1024 x 768 pic in fullscreen mode creates a vertical scrollbar
- decreasing the y pixels by 4 (1024 x 764) makes the scrollbar disappear, but shows me a white border under my image in Chrome for Linux fullscreen mode.

I have no fancy css or html code whatsoever:

```
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let ImageDiv = document.createElement("IMG");

ImageDiv.src = pic.file

content.appendChild(ImageDiv);
```

with only very little of css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

what are the best way to get rid of the border and the scrollbar?

Edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/jLv74co6/1/

Minimal example. not really sure if it helps, as the problem could be related to the chrome Linux version.

Comment: Please post a [repro] for debugging details. So far we can only guess.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I am ot sure this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
body {
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
```

The first two blocks gets rid of the scrollbar on most browsers (all modern ones) and the display block gets rid of the bottom white border for the image

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Do I understand correctly, that this would even hide an appearing scrollbar?

Comment: this hides the scrollbar absolutely everywhere, on the body element and on divs, the only thing is it doesn't hide it on safari on Mac, there is no way to hide that as it appears on scroll, that is a Mac problem and sadly there is zero ways around that but this does the trick for everything else

Comment: I am on Linux fortunately :) Thanks for the explanation!